# How to create index and column for an Excel Dataset in Python

Tags: python, excel, pandas, numpy, apriori

I am doing data analysis with apriori algorithm in Python. I imported the Apriori algorithm into my code page, but the data I have cannot be processed. It is about the sales data of a company. However, the data is arranged so that one product corresponds to each line. As you can see in the visual, I want to change the order of this data. "Produktnumm is" the column titled "lieferungnumm" should not match the column heading. Each "LieferungNummer" contains more than one product. I need to put these products in the cells in the same row as the invoice content, corresponding to the "LieferungNummer" part they belong to. "Lieferungnumm is" contained in the portion of the value must be in the same line of products. In this way, the code will give the correct output. But I can't do this. I share the current state of the data and the situation it should be with its visuals. How can I solve this issue in Python?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I8WeQ.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M2RKu.png)

Comment: please add your code

Comment: Welcome to SO! You might take the [Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and you should (re-)read the help topic [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) to set your expectations. You should at least make an own attempt to get your task done and share the code here. Even if you don't have a good knowledge about Python.

Answer (score 0):

import pandas as pd 
import numpy as np 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

from apyori import apriori

market_basket = pd.read_excel("C:/Users/Lenovo/Desktop/Python_Programlama/reading_data/ornekcalısma.xlsx")
market_basket.head()

market_basket.shape

yeni_veri = market_basket.pivot_table(index="LieferungNummer", columns = "ProduktNummer")
yeni_veri

records = []

for i in range (0,79778)
     records.append([str(yeni_veri.values[i,j]) for j in range (0,7)])

association_rules = apriori(records, min_supprt=0.004 , min_confidence=0.25 , min_lift=3, min_length = 2)

association_results = list(association_rules)

#

in this coden, i take a "0" output for association results